# Commenting blank lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

When commenting multiple lines in vs-code using `ctrl + /`, is there any way to comment the blank lines in the selection too.

Example, if I have the following code,

```
def A():
    line1

    line2
```

When all these lines are selected and commented using `ctrl + /`, I want the blank line to get commented also, like

```
# def A():
#     line1
#      
#     line2
```

instead of:

```
# def A():
#     line1

#     line2
```

Comment: See the duplicate question. There is a new setting in v1.48: Editor > Comments: Ignore Empty Lines uncheck it to enable commenting empty/blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue while using  comment in python There's an option in setting.
Editior >Comments:Insert Space
Turn off

Comment: Wrong setting. see the duplicate question.  There is a new setting in v1.48: `Editor > Comments: Ignore Empty Lines` uncheck it to enable commenting empty/blank lines.